# PineScript proper way of comparing previous indicator data?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

I'm trying to do an indicator on pinescript and I'm pretty much new to the language. This is the code:

```
study("Tester", overlay = true)

ma = ema(close, 50)

signal = (high[1] > ma[1] and close[1] < ma[1])? true : false

plotshape(signal, location = location.abovebar, style = shape.xcross)
```

And my expected result is an x every time the upper wick of a candle goes above the 50 period ema but closes below it. I'm getting Xs where I can't seem to find any reason on why the condition triggers.

[image]

EDIT

Code adjusted to non-shifted bar:

```
study("Tester", overlay = true)

ma = ema(close, 50)

signal = (high > ma and close < ma)? true : false

plotshape(signal, location = location.abovebar, style = shape.xcross)
```

Image of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you shift your signal by 1 bar, so the signal X is printed on the candle when the condition was met on the previous bar.

if you want to plot X exactly on the candle where the condition was met - don't use history reference operator ([1]).

```
study("Tester", overlay = true)
ma = ema(close, 50)
plot(ma)
signal = (high > ma and close < ma)? true : false
plotshape(signal, location = location.abovebar, style = shape.xcross)
```

Comment: Thanks! I come from an mql4 background and I'm not sure if that'd cause repainting here? I mean, will it be calculating bar 0 constantly and therefore potentially causing a repainting issue?

Comment: During the live bar (that is not closed yet) the signal's plot would repaint (appear and disappear), but once the bar is closed (is historic) the plot won't repaint anymore. If you want to run an alert based on the signal - you have to chose in the alert settings "once per bar close" so the alert will fire only when the candle is closed and won't repaint anymore

Comment: The most problems with "repaint" is when the script change the historic values, not on the live-candle value. Live-candle is dynamic and the math based on the current OHLC would change accordingly ofc, but once the bar is closed (is historic) and the script is not changing the historic values - it is not repainting.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to hace the script only updating the plotting on bar close? EDIT: I  just updated the question with the new code but the issue seems to keep happening

Comment: Can you specify the symbol and timeframe from the screenshot? I run the code on various tickers and don't see that behavior. The itself isn't printing the moving average (guess you run MA in a separate script), could be the ma's length is not the same as in the code and in a separate ma script (length 50). EDIT: added ma plot in the code for comparison.